# Transform a pairwise set of values into a matrix

Tags: r

I would like to transform the following dataframe in R:

```
> df <- data.frame(cbind(rep(c("F1","F2","F3"),3), rep(c("F1","F2","F3"),each=3),c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)))
```

into the following matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3, dimnames=list(c("F1","F2","F3"), c("F1","F2","F3")))
```

It seems like apply would be a likely candidate but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Thanks very much

Comment: Why are you using `data.frame(cbind(.))` and not just `data.frame(.)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 res <- xtabs(as.numeric(as.character(X3))~., df)
 attr(res, 'class') <- NULL
 attr(res, 'call') <- NULL
 dimnames(res) <- unname(dimnames(res))
 res
 #   F1 F2 F3
 #F1  1  4  7
 #F2  2  5  8
 #F3  3  6  9
```

Or use `acast` from `reshape2`

```
df$X3 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$X3))
acast(df, X1~X2, value.var='X3')
#   F1 F2 F3
#F1 1  4  7 
#F2 2  5  8 
#F3 3  6  9
```

Comment: Not to nitpick, but your base/"reshape2" comparison might come off as a little bit unfair. In the base approach, you add several lines to try to match the OPs desired result exactly, but you don't do the same with `acast`, which presently results in a factor matrix.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto I did notice that, but I thought the OP's original dataset would be `numeric` for that column.  I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Or by `library(dplyr)` and `library(tidyr)`

```
# assume df is your data frame
df %>% spread(X2, X3)
# you get
  X1 F1 F2 F3
1 F1  1  4  7
2 F2  2  5  8
3 F3  3  6  9
```

If you use `library(tidyr)` alone, could do:

```
spread(df, X2, X3)
```

Comment: +1 You may need to specify `library(dplyr)` for the `%>%` or else `spread(df, X2, X3)`

Comment: @akrun, Using `%>%` is becoming part of DNA. Never thought of it... : )